# PyCharm: Make 'Execute code in console' stop asking me which console

Tags: python, pycharm

I have configured PyCharm (or, to be more precise, the selected interpreter) to leave the python console open when a program execution has finished. I find it very comfortable to debug and watch things like in RStudio: Marking them in the source window and hitting Control+Enter (or 'any control like button'+Enter). So after discovering the 'Execute Selection in Console' Command I was able to run stuff interactively in the console the script was ran in. However, there are two issues with that:

1) whenever I do this for the first time, PyCharm asks me in which console I want to execute the code. Then of course I always select 'the console in which the script was run'.

2) Even though I select the console the script ran in, the marked code is always executed in a new python shell (so it forgets about all the pandas settings for example, i.e. it only prints two columns or so)

Can one somehow make it run the marked code always in the console the script runs in?

See the following screenshots:

1) run the script
[image]

2) change some of the code (i.e. c becomes aa+2*b instead of a+b), mark it and let it run in the console:
[image]

3) PyCharm asks me about 'which console to run the marked code in'???
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Oopsie, I found the problem. In the run configuration I did put an argument to the python interpreter (namely '-i' which causes the interpreter to leave the session open even though the script has terminated exactly as I wanted it) but the solution was to let PyCharm do that for you by selecting the 'Run with python console' option:

[image]

Now every time I run the script it is run in the same console and I can execute code interactively and PyCharm does not ask me anymore in which console I want it to run.